# What is the design motive behind choosing Factory Method pattern to implement ExecutorService?

Tags: java

I am trying to understand the rationale behind providing a method `newFixedThreadPool(int)` instead of a class ( something like NewFixedThreadPool) that can be instantiated using `new`.

In other words, why did they choose to encapsulate classes inside `Executors`?

Comment: Got it. That's probably due to the complexity involved in creating instances of `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is quite a common style in the api, see e.g. `Collections`, `Arrays`, `Paths`, `Files` and so on. I think it has more to do with the design of the api than everything else. The rationale I think is that, rather than requiring you to instantiate new objects, configure and use them, the api provides 'utility classes' which are collections of factory methods for the most common use cases.
This kind of pattern has in my opinion some advantages :

- it lets you accomplish common tasks with (usually) one-liners.
- it prevents you from misusing/misconfiguring objects
- it allows the API to hide the instantiation details from the users, thus enabling future optimizations, refactorings and so on.